# What was the inspiration for the Indian Drakon?

Tags: greek, dragons

The *Drakones indikoi* was a legendary being. The can be found from [here](http://www.theoi.com/Thaumasios/DrakonesIndikoi.html). It says they came from India.

Was this creature inspired by a real animal? If so, can anyone tell what me what it is?

Answer (score 2):

The only vague connection that I can think of is the rivalry between [Ganesha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesha) and [Skanda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartikeya) his brother. Skanda is often associated with and carries around several snakes and ganesha has an elephant head. There is a significant difference in degree in which these Gods are worshiped between northern and southern parts of India. Possibly symbolizing a rivalry.